# Generate html from plain text with formatting markers in Python 3

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, text-parsing

I have written a set of Python 3 scripts to take a formatted text file and move the data into a SQLite database.  The data in the database is then used as a part of a PHP application.  The data in my text file has formatting markers for bold and italics, but not in anything intelligible to a browser.  The formatting scheme is like this:

```
fi:xxxx        (italics on the word xxxx (turned off at the word break))
fi:{xxx…xxx}   (italics on the word or phrase in the curly brackets {})
fb:xxxx        (bold on the word xxxx (turned off at the word break))
fb:{xxx}       (bold on the word or phrase in the brackets {})
fv:xxxx        (bold on the word xxxx (turned off at the word break))
fv:{xxx…xxx}   (bold on the word or phrase in the brackets {})
fn:{xxx…xxx}   (no formatting)
```

I would like to convert each line of source text to (1. a line containing the string, using html tags instead of the source formatting and 2. another line, containing the string stripped of all formatting markers).  I need a formatted and a stripped line for each source line, even if no formatting markers are used on that line.  In the source data, multiple formatting markers of different (or the same) sort may show up in a single line, but you won't find any marker that doesn't end before the line does.

Comment: Sounds like a case for regexp.

Comment: Why don't you use Markdown, or some similarly light markup language, rather than inventing your own?

Comment: I'd love to.  Unfortunately, I'm using data I already have from another source.  The whole reason for my script is to convert it to something more standard, so that I can use it.  The bulk of the conversion works already, but I have this formatting issue left to deal with.

Comment: By the way, I can't figure out a way to do this using regex without slicing the string I've found doing a search and replace, and I can't find a way to slice that string.  If you have a clever way to do this using regex, please do share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format the bracketed sections, you could do something like this:

```
while text.find(":{") > -1:
    index = text.find(":{")
    if text[index-2:index]=="fb":
        text = text[:index-2] + "<b>" + text[index+2:] #insert <b>
        text = text.replace("}","</b>",1) # replace one.
    # else if fi, fv, etc.
```

This will convert "other fb:{bold text} text" to "other **bold text** text".

Then you could convert the space-separated sections:

```
array = text.split(" ")
for word in array:
    if (word.startswith("fi")):
        word = "<i>"+word[2:]+"</i>"
    else if (word.startswith("fb")):
        ....
text = " ".join(array)
```

If you want plain text just replace the tags such as "<b>" and "</b>" with empty string "".

If the formatting doesn't span multiple lines you will probably get better performance reading and converting line by line with:

```
inFile = open("file.txt","r")
outFile = open("file.out","w")

def convert(text):
    #Change text here.
    return text

for line in inFile:
    outFile.write(convert(line))
```

Comment: That could potentially handle my opening tags, but it would still leave me with my closing tags left to figure out.  "}" can mean </i> or </b> depending on which tag it is closing, and it can be several words away from the opening tag.  Also, for tags without brackets, I would still need to generate a closing tag at the end of the word.

Comment: You will probably need to write some regular expressions in the for loop in order to get it to work.

Comment: Even with regular expressions, if I've broken the words up into an array, how will I handle my closing tag if it comes after a different word in the array?

Comment: You can do it piece by piece, without regexp, see updated answer.

Comment: OK, I'm trying to make it work, but still struggling. How do I tie it in to the text I'm working with?  I'm using readline to pull from my file. Also, how am I going to get my clean lines (no formatting)?

Comment: I tried throwing in "text = inf.read()" before your code, and a print(text) afterwords, but stdout just shows me the text file unchanged.

Comment: I've realized that my print command was in the wrong place, so I was printing and reprinting the process as it went on (and it WAS working).  Unfortunately, when I move my print command somewhere sensible (unindent it), the process goes on for an unacceptably long time.  I've yet to see a print, and I've let the script run for minutes on end.  I think that doing my conversion this way may have too much of a performance penalty to be reasonable.  It looks to me like it runs through the text document over and again, making one change on each pass. With a 260,000 line text file, this won't work.

Comment: That latest change did it.  My execution time is still a hair long (26.7 seconds), but nothing like it was before (hours).  This is quite usable. Thanks for helping me figure it out!!